# Is it appropriate to make suggestions for future projects?

Tags: freelancing, contracting

A bit of background: I'm a freelance software developer currently undertaking contracted work for a client. The work we have agreed upon is to develop a working prototype of a product, following closely a specification that we jointly authored. Assuming all goes well, however, more development work will be necessary to bring the product to market.

My client has suggested that I will be considered to continue the work once this first prototyping phase has been completed, which is obviously something I'd be interested in.

**Is it appropriate for me to make suggestions for future development before I have secured the contract for it?** Would this come across as presumptuous? Or should I wait for if/when I secure the contract for the next phase before I make suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. What kind of suggestions are these? Implementation details? Massive changes that require huge redesigns? Something else?

Comment: Beware feature creep - make sure the impact on the delivery date is well understood & probably signed off in writing.

Comment: @Lilienthal The suggestions themselves are less important than the timing. For example though, if I decide during the prototyping phase that a major design would be good for the product, I will still complete the phase on time as per the specification. In this situation, should I suggest the redesign _before_ or _after_ I secure the next contract?

Comment: @DanPichelman Avoiding feature creep is a good suggestion. I mostly included the final paragraph to demonstrate the kind of relationship I have with the client :)

Comment: You think a major redesign would be good but that is less important than the timing.  The question infers minor stuff to me.   Voting to close.  I am not sure what the question is here.

Comment: @Frisbee In my mind, I am only concerned about the timing of any suggestions, not the actual content. I am already committed to to a specification for my contract and, as such, cannot make any major changes in _this_ phase. However, if I have suggestions applicable to the _next_ phase, when should I make them? Apologies if this wasn't clear from the question. Please suggest how I could clarify this.

Comment: But the timing is not independent of the suggestion.    Redesign versus marketing are not the same.  Suggest you ask a specific question.

Comment: So is your concern that you might suggest a project which they then hire someone else to implement?

Comment: @AndreiROM Yes, and whether it would seem presumptuous of me to do so when I'm not sure that the contract will come my way.

Comment: @Jack I'll answer based on this information.

Comment: I suggest things all the time if I think it might benefit the client and therefore possibly be more work for me. There is absolutely nothing wrong with that. 

The only thing to watch out for is feature creep, make sure you're only doing what you're being paid to do and what you quoted on. Depending on the client it can also be a bad idea to give away ideas in such detail that they could do it themselves without you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ideas which you think would be beneficial to the company, speak to them about it.

Arrange a face to face meeting if possible, and make a short presentation on some ideas you have - don't go too deeply into details if you can help it, just a general outline and the potential positive impact it will have on their business.

They will most likely appreciate that you are taking an interest in helping them succeed, but since you also want to lock-in their business, offer a deal:

If they sign on to have you develop all these projects through you over the next 2 years, for example, you will offer them a special rate, and consulting services. The expectations and specifications for each project can be discussed, and established at a later time.

Unfortunately there's no way to guarantee that they won't walk away with your ideas, but you can't succeed unless you put some skin in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Most people prefer someone who can think for themselves. And they usually prefer someone who shows an interest. As long as you look like you are trying to help and not trying to demonstrate that the client's people are stupid.